# How to add switchomega extension to Pycharm robot framework

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I am trying to automate the application in chrome browser, My application uses extension i.e.'SwitchOmega' proxy. How to incorporate this extension into my pycharm IDE

Without this proxy extension, I am getting error to launch the application.